What's the name of this Hindi movie?
I watched a Hindi movie somewhere between 2003-2007. Now I can't recall its name. Here is the short theme of the movie. 
In the beginning, an army officer returns home after a long time to see his family (wife and two children) and stays there with them. As the film goes on, his wife and children start feeling a spirit or ghost is trying to haunt them. When they inform her husband of this feeling, at first he won't believe it and later on he finds that all humans in the town are ghosts and are trying to haunt them. At the end of the movie, it is revealed that his wife and two children are also spirits who doesn't know if they are spirits themselves. They (wife and her children) had committed suicide a couple of years ago for some reason.
This movie's ending is just like same as the Hollywood movie (The Sixth Sense) ending where the doctor himself doesn't know that he is a spirit, which he finds at last.
Can someone let me know the name of this movie?

You might also want to provide a more desctiptive title that tells us something about the film you're looking for.

This movie title is Hum Kaun Hai?.
Amitabh bhachan had played the Army officer Frank and her wife is played by Dimple kapadia.
From IMDB plot summary

After the mysterious disappearance of her maid, butler, and gardener, Mrs. Sandra Williams, the wife of Major Frank, who lives in a palatial house with two children, Sara and David, writes a letter to the local employment agency to get replacements. Martha Pinto, in the company of Edgar and Maria, a dumb woman, apply for these vacancies. Sandra hires them, explains that her children's eyes may be damaged by sunlight, the curtains are to be drawn at all times, as she gets migraines by any loud noise everyone must remain quiet, there is no electricity and all work must be done during the daytime, and the entire house is candle-lit. The staff get busy with their work, and it is then Sarah tells her mom that she has noticed other people in the house that are visible to her only, and she draws the picture of a male, a female (his wife), their son, Vicky, and an elder woman with magical powers. Sandra disbelieves her, but when she starts feeling someone's presence in her house, as well as hearing noises, she decides to investigate. She finds out that the letter she had to the employment agency is still lying in the mailbox. She must now find out how Martha, Edgar and Maria came to know of the vacancies, and of the presence of a album with dead people's photos. Watch as events beyond her control unfold, leading her, Sara and David face to face with the other unseen people in this household.

Synopsis matched not exactly to OPs discription but I know this is movie . Because I have watched in partly in television and then search for it 2  years and found it.
Its story is almost similar to Others with added Bollybood style having two big stars .
